# How to get xcolor colour mixing to work in newcommand

Tags: macros, color

I want to set the colour of a table cell using the argument passed into a command, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's my code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\heatmap}[1][]{\cellcolor{red!#1} {#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Background}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The size and type of repeats}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        Species & genomes & G/C & A/T & Di-\\
        Widget & 7 & \heatmap{97}\% & \heatmap{3}\% & 0\%\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My expectation is that the two cells with the `\heatmap` macro used in them will come out with different shades of red in then but, in fact, they both come out with full red. How can I get the command to work under these circumstances?

Comment: You probably mean to use `\newcommand*{\heatmap}[1]{\cellcolor{red!#1} {#1}}` and not give an optional argument. Otherwise, if you want the optional argument, then it would be `\heatmap[<value>]` in square brackets. But it probably shouldn't be optional in this case.

Comment: @Jon: Well that was a stupid typo... Fixes it. Add as an answer please so I can give you the appropriate reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a case of making the command expect an optional argument (which doesn't seem appropriate in this case).  Compare the difference:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\heatmap}[1][]{\cellcolor{red!#1} {#1}}
\newcommand*{\xheatmap}[1]{\cellcolor{red!#1} {#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{Background}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The size and type of repeats}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        Species & genomes & G/C & A/T & Di-\\
        Widget & 7 & \heatmap[97]\% & \heatmap[30]\% & 0\%\\
        Widget & 7 & \heatmap[57]\% & \heatmap[30!blue!30]\% & 0\%\\
        Widget & 7 & \xheatmap{97}\% & \xheatmap{30}\% & 0\%\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```